# Where is application debug output saved to on iOS simulator file system

Tags: ios, xcode

Where are the debug log of the application output saved in the iOS simulator file system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "debug log" saved "in the iOS simulator file system". If you want to review the console log from an earlier run of your app in Xcode, look in the Report navigator in Xcode.

In this screen shot, every occurrence of the term "Debug" is an earlier run of my app in the Simulator, and the console output during that run is collected here.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the debug log of the app from the command line, something like `xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level debug --predicate '(subsystem == "my.package.id")'
`